Cannot apply condition to grep output in bash script
The data for this script comes from curl and then I grep a few specific response headers. For this example let's focus on "cf-cache-status". This header has 4 potential values (EXPIRED, HIT, DYNAMIC, MISS).
OUTPUT="$(curl -sLIXHEAD https://exampledomain.com)"
    
       
headers=$(echo "$OUTPUT" | grep -iE 'ki-cache-type|ki-cf-cache-status|cf-cache-status|ki-edge|ki-edge-o2o|x-edge-location-klb')

I can use this while loop
while IFS=: read -r header value; do
    echo "$header"
    echo "$value"
done <<< "$headers"

and get this output
cf-cache-status
 DYNAMIC

And this "if" statement within the loop to do the same
while IFS=: read -r header value; do
    if [ "$header" == "cf-cache-status" ]; then
        echo "$header"
        echo "$value"  
    fi
done <<< "$headers" 

For some reason, I cannot use a condition with the $value variable. This condition below does not work as it does for the $header variable. Ideally, I would like to nest if statements, first to find the header and then determine which of the 4 values is present.
while IFS=: read -r header value; do
    if [ "$value" == "DYNAMIC" ]; then
        echo "$header"
        echo "$value"  
    fi
done <<< "$headers" 

Thanks in advance!

The value has a space before it. It's " DYNAMIC", not "DYNAMIC". You could use value="${value# }" to trim off the space.

FYI, == isn't portable in [; the standardized operator is just one =. == will work as long as your script is only run with extended shells, but it's a better habit to be in to use [[ when you're writing code that isn't expected to be backwards compatible with baseline POSIX (and thus ash/dash/posh/&c)

Maybe some issue with CRLFused by HTTP protocol, which are not parsed by read. You may have to sanitize $value by using ${value%$'\r'} for sample.

set -x is your friend to turn on trace logging -- that'll make the arguments to the [ command running the comparison visible, exposing whitespace, carriage returns, and other unexpected content.

grumbles in @F.Hauri's direction about BashPitfalls #50 -- granted, the more explicit/robust approach (populating an array item-by-item in a loop) is longer, and might not fit in a comment.

Thanks @GordonDavisson ! Both your suggestion and F.Hauri's were applied to get this to work.

Thanks! @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub ! Both of your suggestion and Gordon Davison's were required to get this to work.

Thanks @CharlesDuffy for the link and set -x suggestion!
